# How to insert only few columns into one table from multiple tables. do i need to use foreign key to connect tables for this? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables.

table1:

```
item
(
    Item_Name varchar(50),
    Item_Code  varchar(50),
    ItemGroup_Id int,
    Unit_id int, 
    BarCode_Value varchar(50)
)
```

table2:

```
group
(
    @Group_Name varchar(50),
    @Chbox_Val varchar(50), 
    @subGroup varchar(50)
)
```

and

table3:

```
unit
(
    Unit_Name varchar(50),
    Unit_Abbreviation varchar(50),
    Unit_Type varchar(50),
    Description varchar(500)
)
```

I want to insert Group name and subgroup from table 2 into table one.
and unit names from table 3 into table 1.

What should I use? Join or something else?

Comment: What's the mapping between table1 and table2?

Comment: Why are your column names prefixed with '@'?

Comment: Do you want all the rows from table 2 and 3 in 1, or something else?

Comment: i want some of the columns from table 2 and 3 into one.table 2's and 3's primary key is in table 1 as foreign key i.e table2 :ItemGroup_Id  primary key and table 3 :Unit_id  primary key

Comment: table2: group(Group_Name varchar(50), Chbox_Val varchar(50), subGroup varchar(50))

Comment: ignore that @..i have pasted code from my procedure

Comment: @ShitalKashte, what about the rows?

Comment: @ShitalKashte, you can, and should, edit your question.

Comment: @Shital, for the start you need at least primary key for each table.Every logical link must be represented as a foreign key.

Comment: @ivan i have primary keys i.e Id for each table and it is autogenerated.ItemGroutp_id and Unit_id in table 1 are foreign keys of another two tables.

Comment: @andre offcourse rows too.

Comment: @ShitalKashte, your tables do not make a whole lot of sense. Your question does not show how any of the tables are related to each other. And the fact that you use keywords, and invalid symbols would indicate that you are not referring to tables in an actual database.

Comment: @ShitalKashte, for future reference, it would also make your question easier to follow if you just used descriptive table names and used those names in the question. Not all problems can be solved with an additional layer of indirection.